# Compilador acusa erro no código

Tags: c

Sou novo na linguagem C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char card_name[3];
    int count = 0;

    while(card_name[0] != 'X')
    {
        puts("Enter the card_name: ");
        scanf("%2s", card_name);
        int val = 0;

        switch(card_name[0])
        {
            case 'K':
            case 'Q':
            case 'J':
                val = 10;
                break;
            case 'A':
                val = 11;
                break;
            case 'X':
            default:
                val = atoi(card_name);
                if((val < 1) || (val > 10))
                {
                    puts("I don't undstand that value");
                    continue;
                }
        }

        if((val > 2) && (val < 7))
        {
            count++;
        }
        else if(val == 10)
        {
            count--;
        }

        printf("Current count : %i\n", count);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Quando tento executar o código ele me retorna um erro:

```
root@kali:~# gcc test.c -o test
root@kali:~# ./test.c
./test.c: line 3: erro de sintaxe próximo do `token' não esperado `('
./test.c: line 3: `int main() {'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O compilador `gcc` leu o seu código-fonte `test.c` e gerou um arquivo executável chamado `test` (sem o `.c`). Porém ao invés de chamar esse executável (`./test`) você está chamando o código-fonte (`./test.c`). Chame `./test` que vai funcionar.

Comment: Sou muito destraido............